# Application Executable Path C#

Tags: c#, deployment, path, executable

I've added an executable to my Visual Studio 2010 C# Solution. In the properties of this executable, the executable path is a full path ("C:\Test\MyProgram\MyProgram.exe")
When I deploy my solution (with installshield) on a new PC,  the executable is part of the deployed solution together with some source files and the solution file. So far so good. 
But when I open the installed solution file (in Visual Studio 2010), 
I'm not able to build it because It can't find the executable in the specified path:
("C:\Test\MyProgram\").

Here is the question: How can change the full path of the executable, so it gets the path of where the solution is installed on the new PC. Something like : 
"[InstallDir]\MyProgram.exe"

Thanks

Update: I found out that you can use relative path in Application's Executable path. Thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [TargetDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28VS.85%29.aspx) property

Answer (score 0):

I am just thinking off the top of my head here.  There may be a much simpler way.  I'm thinking you might want to create a Custom Action that runs at the end of your installer that manually opens the .xxproj file, and manually edits the path of the reference.  As another poster stated, you can get the new path from the TargetDir property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28VS.85%29.aspx

Example of creating Custom Actions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add your Executable to your Project TO The Main Dir, right click-> Copy To OutPutDirectory -> Copy

this is easiest way to make your file to copy to your target dir, and have your SourceControl Visual studio plugin manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Your executable should be be somewhere in your project source files structure, perhaps in a subfolder. When you add this executable file to project it should then be added on a relative path which is what you want. If this is not happening you should manually edit `csprj` file. To do this, right click on project, unload it, right click again and edit project file.

Of course, your executable file should have its property `Build Action` set to `None` and `Copy to output Directory` to what you want.

If for some reason you cannot add this executable directly into your project files structure I'd suggest to use pre-build event to copy it from where it exists into your project files.